# Publication date of the book of Michael Spivak - Physics for Mathematicians II?

Tags: soft-question, physics, classical-mechanics

I bought the book "Physics for Mathematicians I" by Michael Spivak ([http://www.amazon.com/Physics-Mathematicians-Mechanics-Michael-Spivak/dp/0914098322](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0914098322)), have worked through quite some chapters and love it. I am really looking towards the sequel(s) and wonder how far the author, secretive as usual, has gotten with them. Do you have any information on this?

*Update*: It's very sad to hear Michael Spivak has passed away last year, thanks you [ho-boon-suan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436996/ho-boon-suan) for letting us know.

Comment: Frankly,I'd love to know,too-but since it took Spivak 6 YEARS to write this one and given his advanced age,there may not even be a volume II-except perhaps posthumously. Hope I'm wrong.

Comment: By the way, this first volume seems to has become a rarity - the cheapests are priced above USD 400 in every online store I was able to find. Another reprint of the first volume woud be great too.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: Could you please quote an interesting stuff from "Physics for Mathematicians I" by Michael Spivak to convince me why I must read it? and could it be interesting for me?

Comment: Sad news: Michael Spivak passed away on October 1, 2020 at the age of 80. https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb42-3/tb132beeton-spivak.html

Comment: I am heartbroken to see that he passed away. I am a physicist, and his book on mechanics was by far one of the best I have read.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as shown in the [link](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb42-3/tb132beeton-spivak.pdf) by ho boon saun in the comments, there probably will never be a "Physics for Mathematicians II" by Michael Spivak since he passed away before it got published/fully written - unless someone who personally knew him, and had access to his belongings, could publish his unfinished drafts, which seems unlikely at this point.

On a positive note, as mentioned by Tarc in the comments the first book is rather expensive and was inaccessible because of the cost. However, the Internet Archive [has scanned the book](https://archive.org/details/physics-for-mathematicians-mechanics-spivak/page/n1/mode/2up) and made it freely, publicly accessible. So while we'll probably never get a second book, it can be positively assured that the same book that gave you, and others, joy has been made more accessible for future students.